# Universal multiplication enveloping algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, nonassociative-algebras

I don’t understood what is a universal multiplication enveloping algebra, I studied in Jacobson book, but the concept is very formal and difficult to understand. I wound like exemples of universal multiplication enveloping algebras, what is the multiplication of this algebra and how can I get the universal multiplication enveloping algebra from any algebra $A$?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra?

Comment: Can be, but I do not know what the multiplication algebra means, and how can I compute this?

Comment: Please don't answer "can be". It's your question, if you don't know what your question is about, how can you expect people to answer? Please provide some context, or a precise reference.

Comment: I studied by Jacobson’s book Structures and Representations of Jordan Algebras. Now I want to answer the follow question: Let A be an algebra of dimension n with multiplication 0, compute the universal multiplication enveloping algebra by U_{Alt}(A), for the variety of alternative algebras A.

Comment: Please, can anyone help me?